# Perl dereferencing array for specific value

Tags: perl, reference

So, in Perl, I have an array within an object (so, a reference to an array), and I want to find the first value of that array.

I find myself using code like the following quite often:

```
my $server_ref = $self->{source_env}->{server};
my @servers = @$server_ref;
my $main_server = $servers[0];
```

That works, but I'm sure I could do this without all the intermediate lines and variables.

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
my $main_server = $self->{source_env}->{server}->[0];
```

Comment: All of the arrows after the first are optional. You *can* write it that way if you want, but you'll be more likely to find `$self->{source_env}{server}[0]` in code on CPAN.

Answer (score 0):

Try $server_ref->[0], it should work.